# How can I represent an infinite number in Python?

Tags: python, infinite, infinity

How can I represent an infinite number in python? No matter which number you enter in the program, no number should be greater than this representation of infinity.

Comment: `math.inf` is useful as an initial value in optimisation problems, because it works correctly with min, eg. `min(5, math.inf) == 5`. For example, in shortest path algorithms, you can set unknown distances to `math.inf` without needing to special case `None` or assume an upper bound `9999999`. Similarly, you can use `-math.inf` as a starting value for maximisation problems.

Comment: In most cases, an alternative to using math.inf in optimization problems is to start with the first value.

Comment: Can't help but wonder how so many Python question seems to attract a multitude of ways to do the same thing. How is that Pythonian or compatible with Zen of Python....

Comment: @nyholku agree.. `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.`

Comment: @nyholku It looks to me like the answers here are all substantively suggesting doing the same thing, though. Floating-point infinity is the same built-in object whether you access it as a constant in the `math` standard library or by asking the `float` type to parse the string `"inf"`.

Answer (score 943, accepted):

In Python, you can do:

```
test = float("inf")
```

In Python 3.5, you can do:

```
import math
test = math.inf
```

And then:

```
test > 1
test > 10000
test > x
```

Will always be true. Unless of course, as pointed out, x is also infinity or "nan" ("not a number").

Additionally (Python 2.x ONLY), in a comparison to `Ellipsis`, `float(inf)` is lesser, e.g:

```
float('inf') < Ellipsis
```

would return true.

Comment: Note that infinity is defined in the norm IEEE 754-1985 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985), which Any modern language will rely on. Another point is that, according to this norm, infinity must (obviously) be a floating-point number. This might explain why Python have chosen this akward syntax.

Comment: And you can do `-float("inf")` to get minus infinity which is smaller than any other number.

Answer (score 115):

Since Python 3.5 you can use `math.inf`:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.inf
inf
```

Answer (score 105):

No one seems to have mentioned about the negative infinity explicitly, so I think I should add it.

For negative infinity:

```
-math.inf
```

For positive infinity (just for the sake of completeness):

```
math.inf
```

Comment: How do `float("inf")`, `math.inf`, and `np.inf` compare? Which one to use when?

Comment: @CGFoX Use the first one if you don't want to load packages, that's about the height of it.

Comment: @stefanbschneider under the hood they all use the same floating point representation of infinity as specified by the IEEE 754 floating point standard. So they are essentially all the same. On my machine, using timeit, `float('inf')` took about 185 nanoseconds, whereas the numpy and math versions both took about 70 nanoseconds. This is probably because `float('inf')` has to parse the string and perform some checks. This small of a time is almost always too small to optimize for, but since they are also quicker to type, I don't see why you would use the float('inf') option

Answer (score 35):

I don't know exactly what you are doing, but `float("inf")` gives you a float Infinity, which is greater than any other number.

Answer (score 34):

There is an infinity in the NumPy library: `from numpy import inf`. To get negative infinity one can simply write `-inf`.

Comment: How do `float("inf")`, `math.inf`, and `np.inf` compare? Which one to use when?

Comment: The first two are native i.e. require no dependency. `np.inf` requires the Numpy package. `float('inf')` is a bit hacky as it involves parsing a string, but on the upside it does not even require an import and the parsing is typically computationally negligible. If you use one of the math packages anyway, though, then just use them. If you happen to use both `math` and `np`, then `np.inf` is the shortest one.

Answer (score 29):

Another, less convenient, way to do it is to use [`Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) class:

```
from decimal import Decimal
pos_inf = Decimal('Infinity')
neg_inf = Decimal('-Infinity')
```

Comment: why don't you add _why it is less convenient and why anyone should use it_?

Comment: Main drawback for me is length of this solution, it's not so clear and concise.  But someone might actually prefer this.

Comment: Wouldn't this be an infinity value of a different type?

Comment: Let's see:  `Decimal('Infinity') == float('inf')` returns `True`, so it's pretty much the same.

Comment: His question is if wouldn't it be of a different type and the answer is yes. Should've checked `Decimal('Infinity') is float('inf')` and that's a `False`

Comment: @afzal_SH `float('inf') is float('inf')` returns `False` too

Comment: infinity is different even from itself, so your comment didn't make much sense to me, IMHO

Comment: @nemesisdesign Not true. `Inf == Inf` in standard float arithmetic. Maybe you are thinking of `NaN != NaN`?

Comment: @becko, in python the `==` operator and the `is` operator mean two different things. Try to run in the python REPL the following code: `float('inf') is float('inf')` and `float('inf') == float('inf')`

Comment: `float('inf') is float('inf')` -> `False`, just holds that they are different objects with different instances, but not that the internal contents are different -- actually as @nemesisdesign pointed `float('int') == float('int')` holds to `True`. This is the same problem like comparing mutable objects like [1,2,3] is [1,2,3] and [1,2,3] == [1,2,3], which are, in order, False and True.. More info see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs

Answer (score 18):

In python2.x there was a dirty hack that served this purpose (NEVER use it unless absolutely necessary):

```
None < any integer < any string
```

Thus the check `i < ''` holds `True` for any integer `i`.

It has been reasonably deprecated in python3. Now such comparisons end up with

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

Comment: If you really have yo use this, at least wrap it in some readable names like:
`MIN_INFINITY = None;
INFINITY = "inf";
MIN_INFINITY < x < INFINITY`

Comment: But you don't have to use this.

Answer (score 15):

##### Infinity

**1. Using `float('inf')` and `float('-inf)`**

```py
positive_infinity = float('inf') 
negative_infinity = float('-inf')
```

**2. Using Python’s math module**

```py
import math
 
positive_infinity = math.inf 
negative_infinity = -math.inf
```

**3. Integer `maxsize`**

```py
import sys

maxSize = sys.maxsize 
minSize = -sys.maxsize
```

**4. Using Python’s decimal module**

```py
from decimal import Decimal
 
positive_infinity = Decimal('Infinity') 
negative_infinity = Decimal('-Infinity')
```

**5. Using Numpy Library**

```py
from numpy import inf

positive_infinity = inf 
negative_infinity = -inf
```

Answer (score 13):

Also if you use SymPy you can use `sympy.oo`

```
>>> from sympy import oo
>>> oo + 1
oo
>>> oo - oo
nan
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

For Positive Infinity

```
pos_inf_val = float("infinity")
```

For Negative Infinity

```
neg_inf_val = float("-infinity")
```

Answer (score 1):

Representing **∞** in `python`

`float("inf")` or `float("INF")` or `float("Inf")` or `float("inF")` or `float("infinity")` or `float("Infinity")` creates a `float` object holding **∞**

You can also represent **-∞** in `python`

`float("-inf")` or `float("-INF")` or `float("-Inf")` or `float("-infinity")` creates a float object holding **-∞**

You can perform **arithmetic operations**:

```
infinity = float("inf")
ninfinity = float("-inf")
nan = float("nan")

print(infinity*infinity)#inf
print(ninfinity+infinity)#not a number
print(1/-infinity)#is -0.0
print(nan*nan)# is not a number
print(1/infinity) # is 0.0 since 1/∞ is 0
```

### Output:

```
$ python3 floating.py
inf
nan
-0.0
nan
0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

In Summary, there is two kinds definition for Infinity.

For Positive Infinity

```
posVal1 = math.inf
posVal2 = float("inf")
```

For Negative Infinity

```
negVal1 = -math.inf
negVal2 = float("-inf")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```py
float('inf')
```

Or the math module:

```py
import math
math.inf
```

But if you print it, they will both return `inf`, which proves that `math` uses `float('inf')` as well.