# How to prevent YAML to dump long line without new line

Tags: python, yaml, line-breaks, dump, long-lines

While dumping/serializing data having long lines in input, pyyaml adds extra indentation with new line - which is annoying, how can we avoid this conversion in two lines / multiple lines ?

e.g.

```
In [1]: x = "-c /home/user/test/test2/test23/tet/2s/test1/stest/longdirectory1/directory2/ --optnion12 --verbose"
In [2]: import yaml
In [3]: print (yaml.dump([dict(ATTRIBUTES=[dict(CONFIG=x)])], default_flow_style=False))
```

**WRONG ONE**

```
- ATTRIBUTES:
  - CONFIG: -c /home/user/test/test2/test23/tet/2s/test1/stest/longdirectory1/directory2/
      --optnion12 --verbose
```

**Which should be like**

```
- ATTRIBUTES:
  - CONFIG: -c /home/user/test/test2/test23/tet/2s/test1/stest/longdirectory1/directory2/ --optnion12 --verbose
```

Comment: Did you see the [options of `dump`](http://dpinte.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/pyaml-dump-option/) ? I didn't test it but it seems that some options could help you.

Comment: @MathieuMarques Thanks, It was what I should look for. it worked.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Thanks @MathieuMarques for suggesting to look @ dump options and link provided, YAML documentation was not good enough to find it out.

Anyways solution is to specify `width` parameter for `dump` function.

i.e. `yaml.dump(data, width=1000)`

A better approach suggested by [@RandomCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2439847/randomcoder) to use `yaml.dump(data, width=float("inf"))` for a permanent solution.

Comment: More permanent solution is :`yaml.dump(data, width=float("inf"))`

Comment: _However_, you can't use `width=float("inf")` when using the faster C-based (LibYAML) dumpers (e.g. `Dumper=yaml.CSafeDumper`). In that case something like `width=2147483647` should suffice.

Comment: Alternatively you can probably use [`width=math.inf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30157018/1321680) which may be more readable than `float("inf")` (you need to `import math`).