# Represent infinity as an integer in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, infinity

I am wondering how to define `inf` and `-inf` as an `int` in Python 2.7. I tried and it seems `inf` and `-inf` only work as a `float`.

```
a = float('-inf') # works
b = float('inf') # works

c = int('-inf') # compile error, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'inf'
d = int('inf') # compile error, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'inf'
```

Comment: You can't represent infinity as an integer, but the floating point representation has a special case to allow it. You'll have to use the floating point representation.

Comment: @Jezzamon, using float point representation of inf/-inf to represent int? Could you show me how? `type(float)` !=` type(int)`, do you need a explicit type conversion to convert float into int?

Comment: @Jezzamon, I tried it seems `double('inf')` and `double('-inf')` does not work either?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781260/how-can-i-represent-an-infinite-number-in-python might help.

Comment: @boardrider, thanks and it is very helpful. Looks like no inf for double, only float, correct?

Comment: 'float' in python refers to a floating point number. Unlike other languages, there isn't a distinction between single or double precision floating point numbers. According to the docs, the float type is usually represented as a double precision number behind the scenes.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex

Comment: Is there a particular reason you wanted to represent it as an integer?
Usually in python you should be ok with having all other numbers integers and infinity as `float('inf')`

Comment: @Jezzamon, sorry I have not made myself understood (I understand "there isn't a distinction between single or double precision floating point numbers"). For question on double, actually my question is simple, I mean it seems `double('inf')` cannot compile in Python 2.7? Do I need to import some library to make it compile?

Comment: @Jezzamon, in my program, I just need integer, for example, I represent number of student in a district. Representing as `float('inf')` will make some confusions when others reading my code, so wondering if any `inf` for integer in Python 2.7?

Comment: @LinMa Yes, there is no infinite integer in any version of Python (like most other programming languages). It is ok to use `float('inf')`, I don't think people will be confused because that's the only way to represent infinity.

Comment: @Jezzamon, how about for `double`? I also cannot find a `inf` version for `double`, it seems `inf`only works for `float`?

Comment: @LinMa `double` doesn't exist in python. What are you thinking it is or what are you hoping that to do? Maybe you are getting confused with Java, which has two different ways of representing floating point numbers, `float` and `double`. In python there is only `float`.

Comment: @Jezzamon, thanks for the clarification, yes, I am from Java. I have a sense to use inf of int for int, inf of float for float and inf of double for double. If you could add a reply, I will mark it as answer to benefit other people.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To summarise what was said in the comments

There is no way to represent infinity as an integer in Python. This matches the behaviour of many other languages. However, due to Python's dynamic typing system, you can use `float('inf')` in place of an integer, and in most situations it will behave as you would expect.

As far as creating a 'double' for infinity, in Python there is just one floating point type, called `float`, unlike other languages such as Java which uses the term float and double for floating point numbers with different precision. In Python, [floating point numbers usually use double-precision](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex), so they act the same as doubles in Java.

Comment: As of Python 3.5, you can write infinity as `math.inf` (having put `import math` in your imports), and negative infinity as `-math.inf`.

Comment: @ArthurTacca, type(math.inf) is float and not int.

Comment: @Christian You are right. `math.inf` is now better than writing `float('inf')` as suggested in this answer. However, it gives the same actual value, it doesn't answer the original question any better. I hadn't meant to suggest that it does, but I can see that my comment didn't make that clear.

Answer (score -3):

Something very big that is a integer (made in 3.x, not tested in 2.x):

```
0x40000 #will most likely crash the shell
```

so if you wanted a infinite variable you would do:

```
Infinity = 0x40000
```

You can do any Integer to Hexedecimal here:
https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter
(make sure to add the `0x` before the value it returns for python)

Comment: But `0x40001` is larger than `0x40000`, so it is not a good idea to use `0x40000` as "infinity".

Comment: Also you don't need a website to convert between decimal and hex numbers, when you are using Python.

Comment: I still use it, I don't really want to use stuff that is to complex