# Perform operation on the first instance of a loop that repeats forever

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

Right now I have a script that is meant to loop forever. However, I would like to do something different on the first 'lap' along the lines of the following:

```
import math

for i in range(0,math.inf):
    if i == 0:
       print("I'm gonna start the first lap")
    print('this is one lap')

"I'm gonna start the first lap"
'this is a lap'
'this is a lap'
```

Note that this code does not work because math.inf is a float, NOT an integer. And [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40519631/9525212) says that in Python there is no way to represent infinity as an integer.

Using `while True:` could make sense in this situation, but is there any way to get the function to print something different for first (or the xth) repetition for that matter?

Comment: if you need a potentially infinite integers generator -- take a look at [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to use an infinite `for` loop while keeping a counter, you can use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
from itertools import count

for i in count():
    if i == 0:
        print("I'm gonna start the first lap")
    print('This is one lap')
    # break
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print("I'm gonna start the first lap")
while True:
    print('this is one lap')
```

Put it before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to do that is to put first iteration before the loop:

```
print("I'm gonna start the first lap")
while True:
   print('this is one lap')
```

But, this example does not specify rest of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just count the laps and compare the current lap with the desired lap. For the xth repetition:

```
counter = 0
while True:
    if counter == xth:
        print("This is the xth lap")
    print('this is one lap')
    counter += 1
```