# Find The Closest Number To Numbers Given In A List ~ Python

Tags: python, algorithm

How would you find the closest number in comparison to numbers given in a list?

This is what I have tried so far, but it has been unsuccessful:

```
setted_list = [2, 9, 6, 20, 15]
value_chosen = 17

while True:
    final_value = setted_list[0]
    if setted_list[1] - value_chosen < setted_list[0] - value_chosen:
        final_value = setted_list[1]
    if setted_list[2] - value_chosen < setted_list[1] - value_chosen:
        final_value = setted_list[2]
    if setted_list[3] - value_chosen < setted_list[2] - value_chosen:
        final_value = setted_list[3]
    if setted_list[4] - value_chosen < setted_list[3] - value_chosen:
        final_value = setted_list[4]
print(final_value)
```

My output is always what is inside the value of `setted_list[2]`.
Where have I gone wrong in my algorithm?

Comment: Isn't it an infinite loop, While True:

Comment: what is the condition when it has to break ... lol .. :p

Comment: Lol yeah. It's an infinite loop.

Comment: @zenwraight Yes while True is an infinite loop, but I don't think that's the issue. I tried running the code without the While Loop but it did not change the programs output

Comment: This question is possibly a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141150/from-list-of-integers-get-number-closest-to-a-given-value]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are too new to understand lambda functions yet,

```
   minimum = float("inf")
   setted_list = [2, 9, 6, 20, 15]
   value_chosen = 17

   for val in setted_list:
       if abs(val - value_chosen) < minimum:
           final_value = val
           minimum = abs(val - value_chosen)

            
   print final_value
```

Comment: you need to update `minimum` every time you find a smaller difference

Comment: @Gingerbread, I understand the code, but I do not understand how the variable "minimum" affects the for loop.

Comment: You're comparing two numbers here. For the first iteration, you need something to which you can compare the absolute difference between the two numbers with. Usually, it's a pretty big number that one chooses in such circumstances if you don't know the range of numbers in your list. So I defined minimum to be infinity. Obviously, the first difference (in this case, |2-17| is definitely going to be lesser than infinity. Now, between infinity and 15, 15 is minimum and you want to know if the difference btw 17 and any other no in the list is smaller, so you update minimum variable everytime.

Comment: so if I knew the range of my list, I could change the "inf" inside the float() to that number? Also, how does python know that your referring minimum to infinity, when "inf" is in parenthesis?                                                                           Note: I am a beginner to python, so if the question came of as nooby, I apologize :)

Comment: Check this link out -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781260/how-can-i-represent-an-infinite-number-in-python

Comment: If you knew the range and are sure that the elements are not going to change, you can initialize minimum to any number that is greater than the maximum number in the list.

Comment: The link really helped. Thanks!

Comment: An infinite number is defined like how I did usually. In order to change the minimum variable, you can just assign it to whatever number you have in mind. For ex. `minimum = 10000`

Comment: Please add more description and explanation to your "answer". In that state it is not an answer. e.g. the third comment (yours) is such an explanation. Add to the answer.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a nice, clean simple one-liner: check this out you'll hopefully learn something new  (@ the OP)

```
print min(setted_list,
          key = lambda x: abs(x-value_chosen))
```

The `min()` here does **not** returned the minimalst value from `setted_list`. The question *What is the minimalst* goes to the `key=` argument. The `lambda` function create a `list()` of *the difference between each element in `setted_list` and `value_chosen`.*
The minimalst value is **not** the return value of `min()` but the index of the minimalst value is used to return the corresponding element in `setted_list`.

Comment: How can I get the index of the minimalist value? The one that you assign to the "key" variable?

Comment: @Alessandro ```print min(range(len(setted_list)),key = lambda i: abs(setted_list[i]-value_chosen))```

Answer (score 5):

The loop `while True:` never `break`... you need to find the end point.

maybe you wanted to do something like :

```
>>> l=max(setted_list)
>>> for i in setted_list:
...     if abs(i-value_chosen)<l:
...             l=abs(i-value_chosen)
...             final_value=i
... 
>>> final_value
15
```

you can also do something like :

```
>>> setted_list = [2,9,6,20,15]
>>> value_chosen = 17
>>> min(setted_list, key=lambda x:abs(x-value_chosen))
15
```

Comment: the loop doesn't seem correct to me, you need to initialise a sufficiently large `min_distance` first, compare this with every difference `i-value_chosen` at each iteration and update it every time a shorter distance is found

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [2,9,6,20,15]
val = 17

min_d = max(l) - val
closest_num = -1
for i in l:
    if abs(i - val) < min_d:
        min_d = abs(i-val)
        closest_num = i

print(closest_num)  
#>>> 15
```

Comment: Please add description to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here I use `abs()` to determine the closest value by subtracting it from the original value

```
slist = [2, 9, 6, 20, 15]
value = 17

def closest_value(value, iterable):
    storage = []

    for i in iterable:
        storage.append((abs(value - i),i))

    result = min(storage)
    return print(result[1])

closest_value(value, slist)
15
```

Comment: how is this answer *not useful*?

Comment: Whilst your answer does work, it is unnecessarily complex