# how to express very big infinite number in python similar to C++ INT.INF?

Tags: python, largenumber

when I want to init a number to infinitely small/big so that no other number is larger/smaller - there is C++ version - INT_MIN:

```
int global_min = INT_MIN #infinitely small number
```

what's the python equivalent version for super small, super big number?

Comment: I have to ask, do you really need such a thing?  If you are computing a minimum, you can use the first element of the data set as your minimum value.

Comment: @NathanOliver thx u Nathan - the question is for knowing it if i need in the future.. besides, i just used C++ and transitioning from it

Comment: [numpy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html) has constants like `np.PINF` and `np.NINF` for positive/negative infinity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum and Minimum values for ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966/maximum-and-minimum-values-for-ints)

Comment: Python can also express infinity, look here: [How can I represent an infinite number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781260/how-can-i-represent-an-infinite-number-in-python)

Comment: you have float('inf') and float('-inf')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For infinitely small or large numbers simply use `math.inf` after importing `math`.

```
import math

#x is infinitely small
x = float('-inf')

#y is infinitely large
y = float('+inf')
```

Comment: for clarification: `import math` is not required if `float('+inf')` is used. Alternatively (as described in the answer) one could use `import math; math.inf` (new in python 3.5) which resolves to the same constant (use `-math.inf` for negative numbers).

Comment: You could use [`math.inf`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.inf) and `-math.inf`.

Answer (score 1):

Python supports arbitrarily large integers - the only limit is your memory.
You can create an infinite float, though, and all integers will be less than that:

```
>>> 2**256
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936
>>> -2**256
-115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936
>>> import math
>>> 2 ** 256 < math.inf
True
>>> - 2 ** 256 > -math.inf
True
```