# What is the difference between keyword: is and == in python

Tags: python, syntax, keyword

the python keyword `is` is supposed to be used in place of the `==` operator according to python style guides.

However they don't always do exactly the same thing as shown here. Why? What is the actual difference, and what is the proper usage?

```
import unittest

class testIS(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_is(self):
        self.assertEqual(1,1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Which works... but the following does not...

```
import unittest

class testIS(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_is(self):
        self.assertEqual(1,1)

if __name__ is '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [String comparison in Python: is vs. ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python '==' vs 'is' comparing strings, 'is' fails sometimes, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/python-vs-is-comparing-strings-is-fails-sometimes-why)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**is** will return True if two variables point to the same object, **==** if the objects referred to by the variables are equal.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> b is a 
True
>>> b == a
True
>>> b = a[:]
>>> b is a
False
>>> b == a
True
```

Comment: Marked best answer for providing a quick example :)

Answer (score 7):

`==` tests for equality. Two non-identical objects can be equal.

`is` tests for identity, i.e. whether both refer to the same one object.

Comment: Better is to say `==` tests for value while `is` tests for identity.

Comment: @nightcracker: no, the use of the ambiguous term *equality* is actually acurate, since the definition of equality is defined by the type of the objects.  Unless you override `__eq__` in user-defined classes, `==` checks for identity, not value.

Comment: @André Caron: what the default implementation is, is a guess, where identity happens to be a pretty good guess in Python. But it by no means changes it's semantic meaning, which is test for equality by value.

Comment: @nightcracker 'value' is a subtle term. I can define that objects of a type are equal with probability 0.5 regardless of their value, for example. Or I can have a temporary object 'ignorecase(str)' which can do nothing but be compared for equality with a string. Discussing what value do these objects have seems meaningless for me, yet testing for equality can make sense.

Comment: @nightcracker: The class can make `__eq__` mean whatever makes sense with respect to the abstraction, including equality by identity.  This doesn't have to be equality by value.

Answer (score 1):

```
if money_in_wallet is money_that_was_in_wallet(two_weeks_ago):
    print("I still live with my parents and have no income or expenses")
elif money_in_wallet == money_that_was_in_wallet(two_weeks_ago):
    print("Good, my budget is exactly balanced")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out...

http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in

... Which states...

The operators `is` and `is not` test for object identity: x is y is true if and only if x and y are the same object

Answer (score 0):

The Python keyword 'is' checks for object identity, while == operator checks for equality of values. For example:

```
>>> if Car1 is Car2:
>>>     [do something...]
```

this code tests if Car1 and Car2 refer to the same car, while

```
>>> if Car1 == Car2:
>>>     [do something...]
```

checks if Car1 and Car2 are of same quality, that is if they are of the same model, color, etc.

For this reason, `__name__` is `"__main__"` returns False, because the string `"__main__"` and the value stored in `__name__` are really two different string objects. So to check if the value of `__name__` string is equal to `__main__`, use == operator.

Answer (score 0):

is tests if both inputs are actually the same object. That is located the same address in memory.

== calls the **__*eq*__** method on one of the input objects. Objects can then define their own **__*eq*__** method and decide what is equal and what is not.