# Python: Why operator "is" and "==" are sometimes interchangeable for strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String comparison in Python: is vs. ==](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2988017/1577343)
>   [Python string interning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15541404/1577343)
>   [Why does comparing strings in Python using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1504717/1577343)

I used accidentally `is` and  `==` for strings interchangeably, but I discovered is not always the same.

```
>>> Folder = "locales/"
>>> Folder2 = "locales/"
>>> Folder is Folder2
False
>>> Folder == Folder2
True
>>> File = "file"
>>> File2 = "file"
>>> File is File2
True
>>> File == File2
True
>>>
```

Why in one case operators are interchangeable and in the other not  ?

Comment: Get out of this habit NOW! Comparing strings with `is` is not reliable, and non-portable across Python platforms (CPython/jython/Iron Python). Compare strings with `==`. Save `is` for identity comparison with singletons (like `None`) or objects of your own creation. Do you use `is` for comparing ints too? That is just as unreliable.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I didn't used this but discovered this by accident. And then tried it and discovered the above inconsistency.

Comment: Other relevant questions that could be considered dupe targets: [Why does comparing strings in Python using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1504717) and [Python string interning](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15541404)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short strings are interned for efficiency, so will refer to the same object therefore `is` will be true.

This is an implementation detail in CPython, and is absolutely not to be relied on.

Comment: Interesting python trivia: you can intern any given string with the intern() call.

Answer (score 4):

This question sheds more light on it: [String comparison in Python: is vs. ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs)

The short answer is: **`==` tests for equal value where `is` tests for equal identity** (via object reference).

The fact that 2 strings with equal value have equal identity suggests the python interpreter is optimizing, as Daniel Roseman confirms :)

Answer (score 3):

The `==` operator calls the internal `__cmp__()` method of the first object which compares it to the second one. This is true to all Python objects including strings. The `is` operator compares the objects identity:

> Every object has an identity, a type and a value. An object’s identity never changes once it has been created; you may think of it as the object’s address in memory. The ‘is‘ operator compares the identity of two objects; the id() function returns an integer representing its identity (currently implemented as its address).

E.g.:

```
s1 = 'abc'
id(s1) 
>>> 140058541968080
s2 = 'abc'
id(s2)
>>> 140058541968080

# The values the same due to SPECIFIC CPython behvaiour which detects 
# that the value exists in interpreter's memory thus there is no need
# to store it twice. 

s1 is s2
>>> True

s2 = 'cde'
id(s2)
>>> 140058541968040
s1 is s2
>>> False
```