# Why is this string comparison returning False?

Tags: python, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String comparison in Python: is vs. ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs)

```
algorithm = str(sys.argv[1])
print(algorithm)
print(algorithm is "first")
```

I'm running it from the command line with the argument `first`, so why does that code output:

```
first
False
```

Comment: other duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is):

> The operators is and is not test for object identity: x is y is true if and only if x and y are the same object.

This means it doesn't check if the values are the same, but rather checks if they are in the same memory location. For example:

```
>>> s1 = 'hello everybody'
>>> s2 = 'hello everybody'
>>> s3 = s1
```

Note the different memory locations:

```
>>> id(s1)
174699248
>>> id(s2)
174699408
```

But since `s3` is equal to `s1`, the memory locations are the same:

```
>>> id(s3)
174699248
```

When you use the `is` statement:

```
>>> s1 is s2
False
>>> s3 is s1
True
>>> s3 is s2
False
```

But if you use the equality operator:

```
>>> s1 == s2
True
>>> s2 == s3
True
>>> s3 == s1
True
```

**Edit:** just to be confusing, there is an optimisation (in CPython anyway, I'm not sure if it exists in other implementations) which allows short strings to be compared with `is`:

```
>>> s4 = 'hello'
>>> s5 = 'hello'
>>> id(s4)
173899104
>>> id(s5)
173899104
>>> s4 is s5
True
```

Obviously, this is not something you want to rely on. Use the appropriate statement for the job - `is` if you want to compare identities, and `==` if you want to compare values.

Comment: That edit was really crucial, because I tested it and was thinking, wtf? Nice answer.

Comment: Haha an upvote just brought me back to this question two years later and it's hard to believe how far I've come since then.

Answer (score 6):

You want:

```
algorithm = str(sys.argv[1])
print(algorithm)
print(algorithm == "first")
```

`is` checks for object identity (think memory address).
But in your case the the objects have the same "value", but are not the same objects.

Note that `==` is weaker than `is`.
This means that if `is` returns True, then `==` will also return True, but the reverse is not always true.

Comment: `==` tests if the comparands have the same value, `is` tests if they have the same `id` (roughly equivalent to memory location).

Comment: From a devil's advocate POV feel free to explain why `a = 'a'; b='a'; a is b"` is true

Comment: In python ascii strings of size 1 (well and 0 of course) are stored internally and then shared among variables, like integers. So `a` and `b` are pointing to the same place in memory and therefore identical

Answer (score 3):

Basically, `is` checks object's address (identity), not value,. For value comparison use `==` operator