# Why is my conditional returning "none?"

Tags: python

Whenever I run this I get the third option when it should be returning the first, since s = 'yes'. What is going wrong here?

```
def shut_down(s):
    if s is 'yes':
        return 'Shutting down...'
    elif s is 'no':
        return 'Shutdown aborted!'
    else:
        return "Sorry, I didn't understand you"

ans = 'Yes'
s = ans.lower()
shut_down(s)
```

Comment: This is a repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
if s is 'yes':
```

to

```
if s == 'yes':
```

and

```
elif s is 'no':
```

to

```
elif s == 'no':
```

While `is` [is a valid operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in), it is not the one to use here (it compares object *identity* instead of comparing the character sequences).

Answer (score 4):

`is` tests for identity, not equality. To test if a string is **equal to** `yes` use `s=='yes'`