# In python 2.7 what's the difference between "x != y" and "not x == y"?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is probably very basic but:

Being `X` and `Y` objects of the same class, invoking `not x == y` would cause my debugger to stop in class `__eq__` method but invoking `x != y` would not?

What does `!=` check? Is it equivalent to `is not` (reference checking)?

Comment: In any case, `==` and `is` are _not_ equivalent. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2988271/599884

Comment: I mean, try it for yourself.  `a=list();b=list();print a is b;print a==b`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `!=` operator invokes the `__ne__` special method. Classes that define `__eq__` should also define a `__ne__` method that does the inverse.

The typical pattern for providing `__eq__`, `__ne__`, and `__hash__` looks like this:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    # ...
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, SomeClass):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.attr1 == other.attr1 and self.attr2 == other.attr2

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not (self == other)

    # if __hash__ is not needed, write __hash__ = None and it will be
    # automatically disabled
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.attr1, self.attr2))
```

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from this page, [http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**ne**](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__)

> There are no implied relationships among the comparison operators. The
>   truth of `x==y` does not imply that `x!=y` is false. Accordingly, when
>   defining `__eq__()`, one should also define `__ne__()` so that the
>   operators will behave as expected. See the paragraph on `__hash__()` for
>   some important notes on creating hashable objects which support custom
>   comparison operations and are usable as dictionary keys.