# Python - issue comparing a string that I get from the command line using argparse

Tags: python, string, argparse

I'm having a strange issue with a string compare that seems to stem from my use of the argparse module to get a value from the command line.  Basically the goal is to take in a number the name of a server and from there perform some action...

```
./this_script.py -p 3 -s serverA
```

The number related option works quite well, but for some reason the string related option is failing to pass my error checks.

relevant code is as follows:

```
parser.add_argument("-s", "--server", help="the server on which to act, either serverA or serverB")
```

and then the error checking (and currently debugging

```
if args.server:
    print "server given"
    print args.server
    if args.server is "serverA":
            print "server is " + args.server
    elif args.server is "serverB":
            print "server is " + args.server
    else:
            sys.stderr.write("error, invalid server given\n")
            sys.exit()
```

So when I call the script and pass it the server argument it always goes to the error condition:

```
~> ./this_script.py -s serverA
server given
serverA
error, invalid server serverA given
```

I'm fairly confident that this problem comes from the args.server, as if I hard code the server name then it works without issue.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs

Comment: Look at `'-s serverA'.split()[-1] is 'serverA'`.  If strings come from different sources they may match with `==` but not with `is`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `is` for equality comparison. It tests for object identity, and you have no guarantee that equal strings will use the same object. Use `==` instead.

Try

```
if args.server:
    print "server given"
    print args.server
    if args.server == "serverA":
            print "server is " + args.server
    elif args.server == "serverB":
            print "server is " + args.server
    else:
            sys.stderr.write("error, invalid server given\n")
            sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a case `choices`.

```
parser.add_argument('-s','--server',choices=['serverA','serverB'])
```

even without a custom help line, it gives an error message like:

```
usage: ipython [-h] [-s {serverA,serverB}]
ipython: error: argument -s/--server: invalid choice: 'serverC' (choose from 'serverA', 'serverB')
```

The test that `argparse` uses is the equivalent to `args.server in ['serverA','serverB']`.