# why is this simple in assertion failing in python?

Tags: python, django, assertions

So I have a page that is expected to return content or return a 403 page in django

```
response = self.client.get(...)
print response.status_code
print type(response.status_code)
assert response.status_code is 200
print "WHAT IS GOING ON!?!?!?!"
response = self.client.get(...)
code = response.status_code
print code
print type(code)
assert code is 403
print "hmm"
```

Which returns the output:

```
200
<type 'int'>
WHAT IS GOING ON!?!?!?!
403
<type 'int'>
```

Clearly the code is failing at `assert code is 403` but I can't imagine why. I even sanity checked myself by changing the line to `assert 403 is 403` and the test passed.  I'm new to Python and Django so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: thanks for the nija edits, you just beat me to it

Comment: try `==` instead of `is` because the 200 value is not necessarily the same object that what you are comparing

Comment: the 200 assert works the 403 does not.  and == is a good work around but It would be good to know why.

Comment: [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs)

Comment: If `==` works and `is` does not, then you're using `is` incorrectly anyway.  Testing for equality should be done using `==`.  Is should _only_ be for verifying an object is the _exact same_ object.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, it's actually a pretty interesting issue to run into if you're not experienced yet with the language.

Comment: @Béres Botond The down votes were for some cursing I had forgot to edit out of the code snip-it before posting.  They are entirely deserved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [15]: id(code)
Out[15]: 29536080

In [16]: id(403)
Out[16]: 29535960
```

Using `is`, you are asking if code and 403 are the same object.

As you can see from the ids, they are not. You need `403 == code` to compare values.

Python caches values for small integers from `-5 to 256`, that is why your is comparison worked for 200.

*The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object.*

[from the docs here](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#PyInt_FromLong)

Answer (score 2):

The `is` keyword in Python tests [identity, not equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs).

To put it another way, it tests that two objects are the exact same object.  The object you're comparing, `response.status_code`, is a different object than `403`, likely because the `403` object is a temporary object created on the stack (for lack of a better description).  The two objects will have different memory addresses.

I suppose it's by chance that the test against `200` earlier on worked, but I would expect it to be able to fail for the same reason.