# How do I compare a word from a text file?

Tags: python

I have a text file like below:

```
/john
/peter
/Sam
/Jennefer
```

Using the the following script:

```
keyword_file = open(text_file)
j = keyword_file.readlines()

for i in range(len(j)):
    if j[i] == "/peter":
       print "yes"
```

although `/peter` is in the text file I don't get the printed `yes`.  However when I delete "/"s , "yes" is printed.  What is the problem with it?

Comment: What is `j[i]`, have you looked?

Comment: Do a `print repr(j[i])` and you might understand why your string comparison test failed.

Comment: You really shouldn't read files that way. Don't use `readlines`, just iterate over the file object with `for line in keyword_file:`. Have a read: http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html - or at the very least, if iterate over `j` directly: `for line in j:`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are looking for an exact match on the whole line. This includes any special ascii characters that may be included; such as a [newline character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

If you instead read the text, and [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) it by line, and iterate over the result your code would work:

```
result = keyword_file.read()
for line in result.split('\n'):
    if line == "/peter":
       print "yes"
```

As an alternative you could use

```
for line in keyword_file:
    if line.startswith("/peter"): # or "/peter" in line
        print "yes"
```

If you want to avoid storing the whole file in memory, and still have a clean if statement you can use [strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove any unnecessary special characters or spaces.

```
with open(file_name) as file_obj:
    for line in file_obj:
        if line.strip() == '/peter':
            print "yes"
```

Comment: Feel free to comment on the downvote. The problem with ```for line in keyword_file``` would still cause the same problem with a trailing ```\n``` character.

Comment: Anyway, I was replying to the problem, not displaying the best practice for reading files in Python. There are plenty of articles on that already, and in reality reading the whole string into memory is only really a problem when reading large chunks of data.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Answer (score 0):

First off you're not just looking for `/peter` you're looking for `/peter\n`.

Second, there's a lot here that you can do to improve your script:

1. Use `with` instead of forcing yourself to `open` and `close` your file:

   `with open(text_file) as fp:
       <your code here>`
2. Instead of reading the entire file, read it line by line:

   `for line in fp:
       <your business logic here>`
3. <strike>compare your string using `is` instead of `==`:</strike> [See this SO answer why I'm wrong here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1504742/447015)

   <strike>`if line is '/peter\n':
       <condition if peter is found>`</strike>

Here's the combined script that match what you're trying to do:

```
with open(text_file) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if line == '/peter\n':
            print("yes")  # please use print(<what you want to print here>) instead of print <what you want here> for compatibility with 3.0 and readability.
```

Comment: Completely disagree with point 3 - you should definitely not be using `is` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs Agree with the rest though!

Comment: @eandersson I just checked it and it works correctly.

Comment: @KronoS: It shouldn't work with ```if line == '/peter':```, but with ```/peter\n```, which has been fixed in an edit.

Comment: @eandersson Oh I see what you were saying.  I meant to put that in there, but missed it.  Thanks though.

Comment: What happens if the text file uses ```\r\n``` instead of ```\n```? http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n

Comment: @eandersson then use the following comparison: `if line == '/peter\n' or line == '/peter\r\n':` or use what you suggested: `if line.strip() == '/peter':`.  Doesn't really matter.