# Comparing the value of a Tuples in a List in Python

Tags: python

Say I have a list in python as

some_list = `[(1,'a'),(2,'b')]`

Is there a way I can shorten the following code:

```
def someMethod(some_list, some_string):
    for value in some_list:
        if 'some_string' is value[1]:
            print 'do_something'
```

Comment: *Aside*: Please note that `is` is almost certainly the wrong operator for this. Use `if 'some_string' == value[1]'` instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs

Comment: It would be difficult to shorten that code and maintain its clarity. Why do you want it to be shorter?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `any` function:

```
def someMethod(some_list, some_string):
    if any(x[1] == 'some_string' for x in some_list):
        print 'do_something'
```

The `any` function returns true if any element of its argument is true. In this case, the argument is a generator which produces a sequence of Boolean values, so the entire list doesn't need to be examined: `any` will stop running the generator as soon as it finds a matching value.

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell from the code sample in the question, but I suspect that Kartik wants to "do something" for _each_ tuple in `some_list` that passes the test. And I assume the test should be `x[1] == some_string` rather than `x[1] == 'some_string'`, but his code sample is a little ambiguous...

Comment: When `'some_string'` is obviously a placeholder, it's trivial to replace it with the correct item, whether that is a literal string or a variable. Although on second reading, it does seem pretty obvious that there is no intent to only do *one* thing if any item matches, so this answer is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can flatten the list and check it at the same time.

```
def someMethod(some_list, some_string):
    some_list = [value for item in some_list for value in item if value == some_string]
    for _ in some_list:
        print 'do_something'
```

If you are looking for shorter lengthwise, then you can do the following (less pythonic):

```
def someMethod(some_list, some_string):    
    some_list = [value for item in some_list for value in item if value == some_string]
    for _ in some_list: print 'do_something'
```

Comment: But kartik _only_ wants to check a specific field in each tuple, not all fields, so flattening is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this might be shorter:

```
def someMethod(some_list, some_string):
    for value in itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x[1]=='some_string', some_list):
        print 'do_something'
```

Or even:

```
def someMethod(some_list, some_string):
    print '\n'.join('do_something' for x in some_list if x[1]=='some_string')
```

But, while some of the suggestions are *shorter* than your code, none of them are *more clear*. Clarity should be your goal here, not brevity.

Comment: I agree that clarity is *much* more important than character count, but find the `any` version more obvious that itertools, lambda, join. It also short-circuits.

Answer (score -1):

You have a list of tuples and a string, and you want to `do_something()` every time the string appears in the second part of a tuple.

```
def someMethod(some_list, some_string):
    [do_something() for _, s in some_list if s == some_string]
```

The trick is to get at the second part of the tuple by [unpacking](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples#Packing_and_Unpacking) it into `_, s`, where `_` is a [throwaway variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/underscore-in-python).

Unfortunately you can't execute the statement `print 'do_something'` inside a list comprehension. However, you can call the print function, which will need to be explicitly imported if you're using Python 2:

```
from __future__ import print_function
def someMethod(some_list, some_string):
    [print('do_something') for _, s in some_list if s == some_string]
```

Comment: Don't use a list comprehension simply to replace a for-loop if you don't care about the resulting list.

Comment: And why unpack all fields of a tuple when you only want one of them?

Comment: Aside from it being an anti-pattern in Python, it is inefficient, since you have to spend the time allocating a new list object only to throw it away immediately.