# Regarding matching of substring

Tags: python-2.7

I had coded a simple python program for substring comparison but it is giving me wrong answer
, it should print `the match is found` after matching

```
def myfirst_yoursecond(p,q):

    a = p.find(" ")
    c = p[:a]
    print "the first word is:",c

##Storing the other "bell" word of "p" string in c

    a1 = q.find(" ")
    c1 = q[a1+1:]
    print "The second word is:",c1

## Storing the other "bell" word of "q" string in c1


## comparing the string
    if ( c is c1 ) :
        print "the match is found"
    else:
        print "not found"


## function call
myfirst_yoursecond("bell hooks","curer bell");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does comparing strings in Python using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce)

Comment: Other good answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs).

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` to compare strings:

```
if c == c1:
    print "the match is found"
else:
    print "not found"
```

`is` compares object identity. In this case you have two different string objects with same contents.