# Need Python to register user input in my program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to this site, but wanted to see if anyone could help me here

I am a newbie when it comes to programming, and I am currently trying to make a miles to km / km to miles program, which I based on a tutorial video I watched that taught functions.

I've written this short program successfully in which you can type in a specific amount of miles to convert to kilometer:

```
def miles_to_km(miles):
    amount = miles / (1/1.609344)
    print(miles, "miles are equal to", format(amount, '.2f'), "kilometers" )

miles = float(input("Please type in the amount of miles you would like to  convert"))

miles_to_km(miles)
```

but I want to give users the choice of converting from miles to km or the other way around. This is my code now. Sorry if it's unorganized, I'm am a newbie

```
def miles_to_km():
    miles = float(input("Please type in the amount of miles you would like to convert"))
    amount = miles / (1/1.609344)
    print(miles, "miles are equal to", format(amount, '.2f'), "kilometers")


def km_to_miles():
    km = float(input("Please type in the amount of kilometers you would like  to convert"))
    amount = km * (1/1.609344)
    print(km, "kilometers are equal to", format(amount, '.2f'), "kilometers")

print("Hello, would you like me to convert values from miles to kilometers or from kilometers to miles?")
question = float(input("Please press 1 for miles to km conversion, otherwise press 2 for km to miles conversion"))

if question is 1:
    miles_to_km()
elif question is 2:
    km_to_miles()
```

I don't get errors when running the program, but it finishes after asking the user to press 1 or 2 to choose which way they want to convert, I need help with running either miles_to_km or km_to_miles based on user input.

Hope somebody can help me, it is probably not difficult, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String comparison in Python: is vs. ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs)

Comment: Why `miles / (1/1.609344)` & `km * (1/1.609344)`?  `miles * 1.609344` or `km/1.609344` would make more sense.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are right. Heh, I actually didn't think about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is` operator is used for checking identity (meaning they check if the operands are the same object), not equality . You should use `==` , not `is` . The issue occurs because you are converting the user input to `float` , whereas you are checking it against `int`, they would never be identical objects, Example -

```
>>> 1 is 1.0
False
>>> 1 == 1.0
True
```

Whereas when you check for equality, they are fine. Also, converting the choices to `float` does not make much sense to me, you may be better off converting them to `int` -

```
question = int(input("Please press 1 for miles to km conversion, otherwise press 2 for km to miles conversion"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about the == but that helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

As @MorganThrapp pointed out, your issue is in the use of `is` instead of `==`

```
if question is 1:
    miles_to_km()
elif question is 2:
    km_to_miles()
```

Will compare is the question variable *is the same object* as `1` or `2`

By using:

```
if question == 1:
    miles_to_km()
elif question == 2:
    km_to_miles()
```

You will be comparing the *values*, and should get the correct result.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce) for more.

**EDIT:** @siha I think it should work:

```
will@will-mint2 ~ $ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 12:57:24) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = float(input("enter num:"))
enter num:1
>>> a == 1
True
>>> a is 1
False
```

Comment: Except the OP is converting to `float`, so the comparison will still fail.