# python: string comparison do not work as expected

Tags: python, string, string-comparison

My program is like this:

```
filename=sys.argv[1]
print "filename is default?", (filename is "default")
if (filename is "default"):
  filename="..."
readfile(filename)
```

I type python ....py default in the command line. Then the output is:

filename is default? False

```
IOError:...No such file or directory 'default'.
```

I use `pdb`, and before the if statement excutes, `p filename` returns: `'default'`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

`if filename == "default" :`

**Long answer:**

`is` checks for object identity. To check for equality, use `==`. Check the [Python documentation on comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons). In your case:

Note that comparing two string *constants* with `is` will actually return true.

```
def f():
    a = "foo"
    b = "foo"
    print(a is b)   # True, because a and b refer to the same constant
    x = "f" + "oo"
    print(a is x)   # True, because the addition is optimized away
    y = "f"
    z = y + "oo"    #
    print(a is z)   # False, because z is actually a different object
```

You can see what happens under the hood by disassembling the CPython byte code:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
2         0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo')
          3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

3         6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo')
          9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

4        ...

5        28 LOAD_CONST               4 ('foo')
         31 STORE_FAST               2 (x)

6        ...

7        50 LOAD_CONST               2 ('f')
         53 STORE_FAST               3 (y)

8        56 LOAD_FAST                3 (y)
         59 LOAD_CONST               3 ('oo')
         62 BINARY_ADD
         63 STORE_FAST               4 (z)

9        ...
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what you're looking for:

`if filename == "default" :`

The `==` operator is used for comparison, whilst the `is` operator tests if two variables point to the **same object**, not if two variables have the same value.

Answer (score 3):

Use `==` two compare whether two strings are equal.

Use `is` to test whether it is *the same* string.

Comment: BTW, I doubt you will *ever* want to compare string identities using `is`.

Comment: Hmm, if I try `a = "foo"; b = "foo"; print (a is b), (a == b)` I get two times `True`, any ideas why?

Comment: @adrianus to the interpreter, `"foo"` is a constant. Check out my answer for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @DanielHepper Aah, cool, thanks! I also just noticed that `a = "foo"; b = "foo"; print id(a), id(b)` returns the same value two times...

Comment: @adrianus That is an optimization trick. Interpreter is using the same variable for a and b because it "knows" that they are the same. On the other hand, when you say `filename=sys.argv[1]`, interpreter does not optimize that, because it does not know beforehand what `sys.argv[1]` would be.