# In python why is a list not the same as list[:]?

Tags: python, list

I have a list, `ls = [0 1 2 3 4]` and I am running the following:

```
print(ls is ls[:])
```

I am getting the output as `False`. Why are they not the same list? When I print both versions I get the same list printed.

Comment: `ls[:]` makes a complete copy of `ls`, so they're not the same object. They are equal, though: `ls == ls[:]`

Comment: Slicing creates a copy

Comment: Why would a list copy have to the same id? Then they'd refer to the same list still...

Comment: `is` checks if they are the same object, which they aren't. They are copies. When you do `ls[:]` you are making a copy of the original `ls`.

Comment: @cricket_007 no. The way the question is phrased is different -- just because the answer is the same doesn't mean its a duplicate question. Its equally possible that OP or any general reader understands `is` but not that `a[:]` is a copy operator.

Comment: @gbt So, you say no, but then answer saying it basically is? I'm confused

Comment: It would be annoying (and redundant) if `a = ls[:]` did the same thing as `a = ls`; doing `a = ls[:]` is a very handy way of making a shallow copy of `ls`. FWIW, the other side of the coin is that while `ls = a` binds the name `ls` to the object named `a`, but `ls[:] = a` mutates the existing `ls` object, it doesn't replace it.

Comment: @criket_007 No I said it might be, you said it was. Calling this a duplicate is making an assumption about what the person has misunderstood -- I think its okay to point a person to that answer as it might be related. It is wrong to close it as a duplicate as it has a 50/50 chance of answering the question are therefore could be rather unhelpful and a bit reductionist. If I had come faster and called this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list would I have been any less correct? I assert strongly that this site has become too close happy.

Comment: @cricket_007 Take a moment to notice that the most up voted answer references the copy operator -- which is NOT what this was marked as a duplicate as -- so it was probably closed improperly as a duplicate.

Comment: @gbtimmon Well, **I** didn't close the question, the "Community" thing did. Besides, you got your answer in

Answer (score 6):

`ls` references one object in memory; `ls[:]` creates a *new* `list` object using the same references contained in the first.

```
>>> ls = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> new_ls = ls[:]
>>> id(ls) == id(new_ls)
False
>>> id(ls[0]) == id(new_ls[0])
True
```

Comment: Be careful with that, `id(ls[0]) == id(0)`. Low numbers are singletons in some Python implementations to improve speed and memory usage.

Comment: I don't think that distracts too much from the point at hand, but you can certainly replace `ls = [object(), object(), object(), object(), object()]` without changing the result. It would be a bigger issue if you were expecting `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` to be a list of 5 distinct references.

Comment: Right, just pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically a duplicate of

[String comparison in Python: is vs. ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs)

You just didnt know it.

`==` and `is` check two different things.

`==` asks are these two thing the same value.

`is` asks are these two things the same thing i.e. the same object.

`a[:]` copies the list creating a new list with the same value.

thus

```
a == a[:]
>> True

a is a[:]
>> False
```

Answer (score 1):

`[:]` creates a shallow copy of `ls`, which destroys the new list's original reference to `ls`. Bear in mind, however, that nested lists are not effected by `[:]` and thus, `copy.deepcopy` is required.

Example:

```
s = [5, 6, 2, 4]
=>s
[5, 6, 2, 4]
new_s = s
new_s.append(100)
=>new_s
[5, 6, 2, 4, 100]
=>s
[5, 6, 2, 4, 100]
```

Usage of `deepcopy`:

```
s = [5, 6, [5, 6, 2, 4], 4]
new_s = s[:]
new_s[2].append(45)
=>s
[5, 6, [5, 6, 2, 4, 45], 4] #both sublists are still being referenced
=>new_s
[5, 6, [5, 6, 2, 4, 45], 4]
import copy
s1 = [5, 6, [5, 6, 2, 4], 4]
new_s1 = copy.deepcopy(s1)
new_s1[2].append(100)
=>new_s1
[5, 6, [5, 6, 2, 4, 100], 4]
=>s1
[5, 6, [5, 6, 2, 4], 4]
```

Comment: I don't think the example is the clearest one, using a mutable type method.

Answer (score 1):

`[:]` denotes slicing of a list (slice from start till end) which creates a shallow copy of your iterable object.
To demonstrate further:
When you create a list `a = [1]` and do `b = a`, here you are simply reassigning name of a to b where a and b both point o same memory address

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = a
>>> id(a)
140177107790232
>>> id(b)
140177107790232
>>> b.remove(1)
>>> a
[2]
```

But if you do it with slicing:

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> id(a)
140177107873232
>>> id(b)
140177107873304
>>> b.remove(1)
>>> a
[1, 2]
>>>
```