# Triangle Calculator Python

Tags: python

I essentially need to make a simple calculator, that, when two sides are entered, it produces the third. I'm having a bit of a problem with the sqrt function. This is what I have so far

```
import math

print("It's triangle fun time! Enter the numbers you know, and a ? for the number you don't.")

sideA = int(input("Side A: "))
sideB = int(input("Side B: "))
sideC = int(input("Hypotenuse: "))

if sideA == ("?"):
    print("Side A =", sideC ** 2 - sideB**2)

elif sideB == ("?"):
    print("Side B =", sideC ** 2 - sideA**2)

elif sideC == ("?"):
    print("Side C =", math.sqrt(sideA)**2 + (sideB)**2)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit - code updated

(there are not spaces between sideC and ** and 2, but it was bolding it so I changed it)

Comment: you do not need to write `str("?")`, it's already a string

Comment: Changed, thank you

Comment: You should also [*never* use `is` for equality testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce#1504742); the fact that it works here is an implementation detail of CPython and subject to change.

Comment: I didn't think I was meant to but I forgot about == and = wasn't working haha

Comment: Better link than that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2988117/3650362

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful!

Comment: Incidentally there is also the [`math.hypot`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html#math.hypot) function. Only solves part of your problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

import math

print("It's triangle fun time! Enter the numbers you know, and a '0' for the number you don't.")

sideA = (int(input("Side A: ")))

sideB = (int(input("Side B: ")))

sideC = (int(input("Hypotenuse: ")))

if sideA is 0:

```
sideA = math.sqrt((sideC**2) - (sideB**2))
print("Side A =", sideA)
```

if sideB is 0:

```
sideB = math.sqrt((sideC**2) - (sideA**2))
print("Side B =", sideB)
```

if sideC is 0:

```
sideC = math.sqrt((sideA**2) + (sideB)**2)
print("Side C =", sideC)
```

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you are using Python 3.

- The `input()` function returns a string, not an integer. You will need to convert it from a string to an integer after you have checked that it isn't a `?` input. To do this, use [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#int)
- Don't use `is` for comparison, use `==`
- Did you import the `sqrt` function from the math module?

Comment: I changed those things, however I'm still having this problem when I try to import sqrt, and if I don't it says I need to

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Problem 5.py", line 2, in <module>
    math.sqrt()
TypeError: sqrt() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Comment: @mememan9001 The code you have shown above does not reflect this then. When you use `math.sqrt()`, you need to add in a number - an argument to the function -  (eg: `math.sqrt(4)` will return 2)

Comment: I've changed the last line to be

 print("Side C =", math.sqrt(sideA **2 + sideB **2))

But I still get

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Problem 5.py", line 16, in <module>
    print("Side C =", math.sqrt(sideA **2 + sideB **2))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Yes - use `int()` to convert a string from an integer to avoid TypeErrors. Apologies, I didn't make that clear in my answer

Comment: Okay I think I know what you're saying but I'm having trouble actually doing it. I changed the (input) to be (int(input)) for the sides but now I'm getting this

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Problem 5.py", line 7, in <module>
    sideC = int(input("Hypotenuse: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '?'

Comment: @mememan9001 Yes. Convert it to an integer *after* you check for `?`. So do `print("Side C =", math.sqrt(int(sideA)**2 + int(sideB)**2))`, where A and B are not question marks

Comment: I'm still having the same error as above, and I typed exactly what you just did

Comment: @mememan9001 And was your input two real numbers and a ? for A/B/C ?

Comment: Yep, every time I've been doing two numbers and a question mark, usually 3, 5, ?, but mixing it up to test every now and then

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Problem 5.py", line 7, in <module>
    sideC = int(input("Hypotenuse: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '?'

Comment: @mememan9001 Remove the `int()` around all inputs since you don't know whether the input will be of integer format or not

Comment: @mememan9001 Edit your question and post the full code you have right now

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported math in order to use `sqrt()`?

```
import math
math.sqrt(4)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Problem 5.py", line 2, in <module>
    math.sqrt()
TypeError: sqrt() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Comment: You put what you want to take the square root of inside the 'math.sqrt()' if you leave the () empty you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Math in ℝ is in the [math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) module.

Correspondingly, math in ℂ is in [cmath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html).

Comment: `R` -> `python`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I think that's supposed to be the domain of Real numbers, but this isn't really an answer.

Comment: Damn, so many downvotes here. Ignacio is referring to the domain of real numbers here, not the programming language R. He is not wrong - especially when OP hasn't given us all information

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
# Your code here
math.sqrt( sideA **2 + sideB **2 )
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Problem 5.py", line 16, in <module>
    print("Side C =", math.sqrt( sideA **2 + sideB **2 ))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'

Comment: As stated above, input() function returns a string, not a number. So, you need to convert your input into number values. You can try: numA = float(sideA), numB = float(sideB). And then numC = math.sqrt(numA **2 + numB **2 )