# Compare unicode to str Python3

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, arduino, serial-communication

I am working on a project in which i am getting data from an arduino over serial communication. So i open a `ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM1', 9600)` and everything is working fine. The thing is that i wrote this code to check when the data i get is 0 but i can't get it work.

```
while True:
            try :
                a = ser.readline()

                # i do that because the input stream is smthg like b' 16.894548\r\n'
                data = a.decode('utf-8') 

                print(a is str(str(0).encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8', "strict")))
```

I have tried many things, like getting the sizeof, encode and decode, making everything a `str` after decoding. But still no luck.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Use `==` to compare strings, not `is`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs)
- Note that you have new line characters in the end. `'0' != '0/r/n'`.

  Try

  ```
  a = ser.readline()
  print(a.decode().strip() == '0')
  ```

Comment: Yeap! That is the solution. That helped me a lot.
Thank you again!