# List comprehension not working for a generator

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm using list comprehension to get counts of value of a key in each dictionary yielded by a generator, but I'm not sure if I'm using the right syntax, because I get 0 results:

```
ln_is = [d['url'] for d in generator if d['url_source'] is '"http://ln.is']
```

I am sure that the dictionaries in this generator has those values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs

Comment: `is` should never be used to compare strings, unless you're a bona expert playing deep, deep tricks.  Use `==` instead I bet it will work.

Comment: @TimPeters I also wonder because some the urls are None? Should I do ln_is = [d['url'] for d in generator if d['url_source'] is not None and '"http://ln.is']

Comment: `None` never compares equal to a string, nor does an attempt raise an exception - `None` just isn't an issue here.