# Python - iterating over nested loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

First off i am certain that such a basic thing has been asked before, but i could not find a post about it.

I have this piece of example data:

```
'192.168.244.213': ['8', '4', '3', '1', '6', '5', '3', '2', '6', '5'], 
'192.168.244.214': ['6', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '2', '7', '5', '5'], 
'192.168.244.215': ['4', '10', '0', '8', '7', '0', '4', '3', '2', '6'], 
'192.168.244.230': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

And i want to print out every line (each line is one dictionary key-value pair) that has a list-value whose list contains any amount of items that is not 0 (in this case, every line except the 4th)

I just cant seem to figure out this seemingly simple thing - what i tried before was those two things:

```
for i in d.keys():
    if "0" not in d[i]:
        print(i, d[i])
```

This one shows only lists that do not contain 0 AT ALL - so the third line would not be shown, even though it contains non-0 values

```
for i in d.keys():
    for j in d[i]:
        if j is not "0":
            print(i, d[i])
```

This one DOES show me what i want, but as you can tell, it prints every result way too often - one print for every list value that is not 0.

Comment: The key is the IP? and the values are chars in a list?

Comment: the value is the list itself, so its IP:list

Comment: The problem is that `if "0" not in d[i]` checks if 0 is in the list at all, so obviously it would skip line 3 as well. Austin's answer seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is basically just a missing break:

```
for i in d.keys():
    for j in d[i]:
        if j != "0":
            print(i, d[i])
            break
```

However, for conciseness I would recommend you check out the `any()` function, which does exactly what you want: Return true if any of the elements of the iterable are `true` (when cast to booleans).

Eg:

```
for i in d.keys():
    if any(j != "0" for j in d[i]):
        print(i, d[i])
```

(The `j is not "0"` generator is only necessary because you have string values. For an int array, `any(d[i])` would work.)

Even more "Pythonic" would be removing the need for a dictionary lookup:

```
for i, d_i in d.items():
    if any(j != "0" for j in d_i):
        print(i, d_i)
```

Comment: You should avoid comparing strings with `is not`. Use `!=`.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I didnt use `break` before, i always had struggles with nested loops because of that!

Comment: About "is not": Thanks, the OP's code indeed has another potential bug there; I've now fixed this. (See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs on this topic.)

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary-comprehension:

```
d = {'192.168.244.213': ['8', '4', '3', '1', '6', '5', '3', '2', '6', '5'],
     '192.168.244.214': ['6', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '2', '7', '5', '5'],
     '192.168.244.215': ['4', '10', '0', '8', '7', '0', '4', '3', '2', '6'],
     '192.168.244.230': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']}

result = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if not all(x == '0' for x in v)}

# {'192.168.244.213': ['8', '4', '3', '1', '6', '5', '3', '2', '6', '5'],
#  '192.168.244.214': ['6', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '2', '7', '5', '5'],
#  '192.168.244.215': ['4', '10', '0', '8', '7', '0', '4', '3', '2', '6']}
```

The above code generates a new dictionary which omits all items where values are all zeros.

Now that you have a dictionary, you can easily do an iteration like so:

```
for k, v in result.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: looks good! as a small bonus, can you tell me how i would print out every key:value pair in a new line?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply iterate over like

```py
def all_zero(arr):
    for i in arr:
        if i != 0:
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

You can call it on all the lists one by one.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in d.keys():
    all_zero = True
    for j in d[i]:
        if j is not "0":
            all_zero = False
            break
    if not all_zero:
        print(i, d[i])
```

This may work for almost every language :)

Answer (score 1):

I like the other answers but I feel like you can get away with something like this as well:

```py
for i in d.keys():
    #If there are as many zeroes as there are elements in the list...
    if d[i].count(0) == len(d[i]):
        #...You might as well skip it :)
        continue
    print(d[i])
```

Comment: This didnt work for me, it only prints the values and it doesnt filter out values that contain only 0s - it works when you count `"0"`, because my lists didnt contain int 0 though, so thanks!

Comment: Ah, right, didn't notice you were using strings instead of ints. Should work with any char/value though as long as you replace the count to whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at how I could accomplish this.

```
d = {
    '192.168.244.213': ['8', '4', '3', '1', '6', '5', '3', '2', '6', '5'], 
    '192.168.244.214': ['6', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '2', '7', '5', '5'], 
    '192.168.244.215': ['4', '10', '0', '8', '7', '0', '4', '3', '2', '6'], 
    '192.168.244.230': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
}

for key in d.keys():
    if all( item == '0' for item in d[key]):
        pass
    else:
        print(key, d[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `all` in this case, consider following example:

```
digits = ['0', '2', '0', '4', '7', '5', '0', '3', '2', '6']
zeros = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
print(all([k=='0' for k in digits])) #gives False
print(all([k=='0' for k in zeros])) #gives True
```

Please remember to deliver `[k=='0' for k in ...]` to `all`, as delivering list directly would give `True` for both `digits` and `zeros`, as both contain at least one non-empty `str` (`str` of length `1` or greater).