# python - condensing comparisons

Tags: python, comparison, comparison-operators

I'm a new member here and also new to python. My question is as follows, is it valid to have a line like this?

```
if x or y is 'whatever':
```

I tested this in the interpreter and am getting inconsistent results. It would seem that this line yields more consistent and expected results

```
if (x or y) is 'whatever':
```

Or is it always best to explicitly have everything laid out as such

```
if x is 'whatever' or y is 'whatever':
```

This last one always works but I'm just trying to make my code a bit more concise while still following best practices. I tried doing a search so as not to ask a redundant question but searching for 'is' 'or' and 'and' is rather difficult. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

edit: Thanks all for the quick replies. This works perfectly for me when I need 'or'

```
if 'whatever' in [x,y]:
```

But how would I condense this if I need an 'and'?

```
if x == 'whatever' and y == 'whatever':
```

Comment: To your last question, the answer is ``if x==y=='whatever'``

Comment: That means: there's a string object in the memory, whose value is 'whatever', and the object pointed to by the reference whose name is _x_ and the object pointed to by the reference whose name is _y_ are this same object of value 'whatever'. _x_ and _y_ are identifiers ,that is to say strings that are names of variables whose nature is to be pointers, and these pointers point to objects **x** and **y**. The data model of Python is : _x_ identifier, underlying pointer (called reference in Python) of name _x_, the reference points to the object **x**. Think like that and you'll have no problems

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`or` doesn't work like it does in English.

`x or y` returns x if x is a true-ish value, otherwise it returns y.  Strings are true-ish if they are not empty.

Worse, "is" has a higher precedence that "or", so your expression is the same as `x or (y is 'whatever')`.  So if x is not empty, it returns x (which will be true, so the if will execute).  If x is empty, it will evaluate `y is 'whatever'`.

BTW: Don't use "is" to compare value equality, use ==.

You want this (parens optional):

```
if (x == 'whatever') or (y == 'whatever'):
```

or more concise, but stranger:

```
if 'whatever' in [x, y]:
```

Comment: Perhaps I've been at this too long, but I don't see how the last bit is at all strange.

Comment: `x or y` returns `x` if it is true, otherwise it returns `y`. It won't return `False` unless `x` is false and `y` itself is `False`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Yes! I went too fast, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Python is not English.

```
if x or y is 'whatever':
```

means:

```
if x or (y is 'whatever'):
```

Which is X is true OR y is 'whatever'

```
if (x or y) is 'whatever':
```

`x or y` becomes either x or y. If x is true, then it returns X otherwise it becomes Y. Then the result of that is compared to 'whatever'.

You should never never compare strings with `is` anyways. String should be compared using `==`. is means something different which sometimes works by accident.

You actual request can be written as:

```
if 'whatever' in [x,y]:
```

This checks whether the string whatever is in the list `[x,y]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work:

```
if "whatever" in (x, y):
```

It's kind of weird though.

Answer (score 1):

```
if x or y is 'whatever' # this is akin to if x or (y is 'whatever')

if (x or y) is 'whatever': # (x or y) returns the first non-false value...

if x is 'whatever' or y is 'whatever': # this is valid and correct (aside from the fact you shouldn't be using `is`, see below)
```

You may have

```
if 'whatever' in (x, y)
```

or, in case of a longer list of conditions, it's nice to use the '[any](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any)' function:

```
if any([condition(k) for k in list])
```

But it's overkill in the case you exposed, since you just want to know if 'whatever' is contained in [x, y].

UPDATE:

consider that 'is' is actually comparing the memory addresses, and (as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987958/how-is-the-is-keyword-implemented-in-python/2987975#2987975)) it's not good practice to use it on strings.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not finding the second case to always be false, at least in the interpreter.

Comment: thinc is correct. Python's version of "x or y" return either one of x,y not an actual boolean value. Also, What's the point of your `any` construction compared to just using in on the whole list? Also, you still say that using is on your third line is valid and correct. (Ok, yes, I'm being a stickler here)

Comment: @WinstonEwert I made my point a bit clearer (hopefully!): the question is about condensing conditional statements, so I went a bit more general; you are totally right in the sense that "'whatever' in [x, y]" would be perfectly enough in that case.