# Is the "is" Python operator reliable to test reference equality of mutable objects?

Tags: python, reference, identity, equality, mutable

I know the `is` operator in Python has an unexpected behavior on immutable objects like integers and strings. See ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

```
>>> a = 0
>>> b = 0
>>> a is b
True        # Unexpected, we assigned b independently from a
```

When it comes to **mutable objects**, are we guaranteed that two variables expected (as written in the code) to reference two distinct objects (with equal value), will not be internally bound to the same object ? (Until we mutate one of the two variables, then of course the references will differ.)

```
>>> a = [0]
>>> b = [0]
>>> a is b
# Is False guaranteed ?
```

Put in other words, if somewhere `x is y` returns `True` (`x` and `y` being mutable objects), are we guaranteed that mutating `x` will mutate `y` as well ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When, if ever, to use the 'is' keyword in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885931/when-if-ever-to-use-the-is-keyword-in-python)

Comment: Yes, `a is b` will always be false in your second example. Also `is` is a reliable test for reference equality for immutablele objects — the surprising behavior comes from the fact that python reuses objects sometimes when they are immutable. You just can't count on that happening.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-maintained-by-the-interpreter

Comment: `is` should only ever be used for identity. If the semantics of your code are asking about identity, go nuts. For any other use cases, don't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as you think some "is" behavior is "unexpected", your mental model falls short of reality ;-)

Your question is *really* about when Python guarantees to create a new object.  And when it doesn't.  For mutable objects, yes, a constructor (including a literal) yielding a mutable object always creates a new object.  That's why:

```
>>> a = [0]
>>> b = [0]
>>> a is b
```

is always `False`. Python *could* have said that it's undefined whether each instance of `[0]` creates a new object, but it doesn't: it guarantees each instance always creates a new object.  `is` behavior is a *consequence* of that, not a driver of that.

Similarly,

```
>>> a = set()
>>> b = set()
>>> a is b
False
```

is also guaranteed. Because `set()` returns a mutable object, it always guarantees to create a new such object.

But for immutable objects, it's **not defined**.  For example, the result of this is not defined:

```
>>> a = frozenset()
>>> b = frozenset()
>>> a is b
```

`frozenset()` - like integer literals - returns an immutable object, and it's up to the implementation whether to return a new object or reuse an existing one.  In this specific example, `a is b` is `True`, because the implementation du jour *happens* to reuse an empty frozenset. But, e.g., it just so happens that

```
>>> a = frozenset([3])
>>> b = frozenset([3])
>>> a is b
False
```

today. It could just as well return `True` tomorrow (although that's unlikely - while an empty frozenset is an easy-to-detect special case, it would be expensive to ensure uniqueness across all frozenset objects).