# Python comparison operator not giving proper answer in if-else statements

Tags: python-3.x, comparison-operators

```
# Program1: Take two numbers as input from User and print which one is greater or are they equal.

num1 = input("Enter the first number: ")
num2 = input("Enter the second number: ")
if num1 is num2:
    print("The two numbers are equal")
elif num1 < num2:
    print("The first number is less than the second number")
else:
    print("The first number is greater than the second number")
```

Enter the first number: -10
Enter the second number: -20
The first number is less than the second number

Process finished with exit code 0

What is wrong in above code to compare two numbers? How come python missing basic -ve number comparison?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When, if ever, to use the 'is' keyword in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885931/when-if-ever-to-use-the-is-keyword-in-python)

Comment: Also, your inputs are string values - comparing them like `num1 < num2` compares the strings _lexicographically_ (basically, alphabetically). If you want to compare them numerically, you'll need to parse those strings into numbers.

Answer (score 1):

First,
`input()` returns `string`. SO you need to cast the input values to integer by using `int()`.

Second,
when you use `if num1 is num2:`, the `is` operator(keyword) is testing if `num1`and `num2`refer to the same object or not.

Third,
**Enter the first number: -10 Enter the second number: -20 The first number is less than the second number**

**Process finished with exit code 0**

You know that -10 and -20 are numbers, but as mentioned in First Para above, `input()`is returning `string` values, python is doing lexicographical comparison, and **ascii** of **-** is highter than digit.

So, your code should be like this instead

```
num1 = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter the second number: "))

if num1 == num2:
    print("The two numbers are equal")
elif num1 < num2:
    print("The first number is less than the second number")
else:
    print("The first number is greater than the second number")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use '==' statement instead of 'is' statement.

'==' actually compare the value where 'is' check if they are same object.

See [a previous discussion about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)

Comment: Since what he tries to do is to not only check if they are the same value but also to check what value is higher/lower the best way to do it is to parse the inputs to int values and then do those comparisons instead of just using the  '==' statement.

Comment: Since what he tries to do is to not only check if they are the same value but also to check what value is higher/lower the best way to do it is to parse the inputs to int values and then do those comparisons instead of just using the '==' statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a string comparison, not a numerical comparison. The string "-10" does come before "-20" since "1" comes before "2" in lexicographical order. To do an integer comparison you should cast the values you receive to int:

```py
num1 = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
```