# Why does a lowercase string and string.lowercase returns False

Tags: python

```
s="wall"
d="WALL".lower()
```

`s is d` returns `False`.
s and d are having the same string. But Why it returned False?

Comment: [How is the 'is' keyword implemented in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987958/how-is-the-is-keyword-implemented-in-python)

Comment: where did you learn about `is`?  you should very, very rarely be using it.

Comment: @Eevee I came across is when I searched for string operations.

Answer (score 2):

`==` tests for equality.  `a == b` tests whether `a` and `b` have the same value.

`is` tests for identity — that is, `a is b` tests whether `a` and `b` are in fact the *same object*.  Just don't use it except to test for `is None`.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be misunderstanding the `is` operator. This operator returns true if the two variables in question are located at the same memory location. In this instance, although you have two variables both storing the value "wall", they are still both distinct in that each has its own copy of the word.

In order to properly check String equality, you should use the `==` operator, which is value equality checking.

Answer (score 1):

"is" keyword compares the objects IDs, not just whether the value is equal.
It's not the same as '===' operator in many other languages.
'is' is equivalent to:

```
id(s) == id(d)
```

There are some even more interesting cases. For example (in CPython):`

```
a = 5
b = 5
a is b # equals to True
```

but:

```
c = 1200
d = 1200
c is d # equals to False
```

The conclusion is: don't use 'is' to compare values as it can lead to confusion.

Comment: Good answer, but it would be better to either omit the last part or explain it. The way it is might be confusing to beginners.

Answer (score 0):

By using `is` your are comparing their identities, if you try `print s == d`, which compares their values, you will get true.

Check this post for more details: [String comparison in Python: is vs. ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs)

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` to compare objects for equality. Use `is` to check if two variables reference the exact same objects. Here `s` and `d` refer to two distinct string objects with identical contents, so `==` is the correct operator to use.