# django custom template tag - if else condition

Tags: python, django, date, django-templates

I have been trying to write my 1st [django custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/), by reading the django docs.

The custom template tag I have written contains a conditional if elseif else condition.

The result is always returning the else condition.

Here is my custom template tag code:

```
@register.filter(name='replace_date_separator')
def replace_date_separator(value, arg):

if arg is 'fr-CA':
    return value.replace("/", '-')
elif arg is 'de' or arg is 'pl' or arg is 'ru':
    return value.replace("/", '.')
else:
    return value.replace("/", '*')
```

Here is my template tag:

```
{{ voluntary_detail.voluntary_finish_date|date:'m/Y'|replace_date_separator:voluntary_detail.language_version.language_code }}
```

The *voluntary_detail.language_version.language_code* above is the two letter language code - ru, de, en, pl, etc.

Comment: This question is in the top five results for "django custom if else tag", also it is a question about filters. Changing the title to "django custom filter - if else condition" would help to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the [`is`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#is) keyword, [which checks for object identity match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2987975/1860929), and hence, always fails.

Instead use `==` to check for equality, and do:

```
@register.filter(name='replace_date_separator')
def replace_date_separator(value, arg):

    if arg == 'fr-CA':
        return value.replace("/", '-')
    elif arg == 'de' or arg == 'pl' or arg == 'ru':
        return value.replace("/", '.')
    else:
        return value.replace("/", '*')
```

As an aside, you can simplify the `elif` statement to `elif arg in ('de', 'pl', 'ru'):`

Comment: mu 無, Thanks. I actually did have the == and it would not work, but tried is and left that in when I copied the code to the thread. Thanks also for the simplified code too.