# Iterate over a list inside a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Lets say I have a dictionary like this:

```
myDict = {
    1: {
        "a": "something",
        "b": [0, 1, 2],
        "c": ["a", "b", "c"]
    },
    2: {
        "a": "somethingElse",
        "b": [3, 4, 5],
        "c": ["d", "e", "f"]
    },
    3: {
        "a": "another",
        "b": [6, 7, 8],
        "c": ["g", "h", "i"]
    }
}
```

And this is my code:

```
for id, obj in myDict.items():
    for key, val in obj.items():
        if key is "b":
            for item in val:
                # apply some function to item
```

Is there a better way to iterate over a list inside a nested dict? Or is there a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: `if key is "b"`, but what about `"c"`? They are lists too. You don't want them?

Comment: @gill I don't need "c". I only need values from "b" because I need to apply some function for each value inside the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dictionary is always two levels deep, I don't see anything wrong with your approach. In your implementation, I would use `key == "b"` rather than `key is "b"`. Using `is` will test for identity (e.g. `id(a) == id(b)`), while `==` will test for equality (e.g. `a.__eq__(b)`). This functions the same way when I test it in IDLE, but it's not a good habit to get into. There's more info on it here: [How is the 'is' keyword implemented in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987958/how-is-the-is-keyword-implemented-in-python)

If you want to deal with varying level dictionaries, you could use something like:

```
def test_dict_for_key(dictionary, key, function):
    for test_key, value in dictionary.items():
        if key == test_key:
            dictionary[key] = type(value)(map(function, value))
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            test_dict_for_key(value, key, function)
```

An example usage might be something like:

```
myDict = {
    1: {
        "a": "something",
        "b": [0, 1, 2],
        "c": ["a", "b", "c"]
    },
    2: {
        "a": "somethingElse",
        "b": [3, 4, 5],
        "c": ["d", "e", "f"]
    },
    3: {
        "a": "another",
        "b": [6, 7, 8],
        "c": ["g", "h", "i"]
    }
}

# adds 1 to every entry in each b
test_dict_for_key(myDict, "b", lambda x: x + 1)

# prints [1, 2, 3]
print(myDict[1]["b"])
```

Comment: Pretty much answers all of my questions, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely do not need to iterate the *list* to print it (unless this is a functional requirement for the code you are writing).

Very simply, you could do this:

```
for id, obj in myDict.items():
    if "b" in obj:
        print obj["b"]
```

To map the list object, represented by `obj['b']` to another function, you can use the `map` function:

```
map(foo, obj["b"])
```

Comment: I don't want to just print it. I need to apply some function for each value inside the list.

Comment: OK, then in my answer you could do `map(foo, obj['b'])` instead of `print`.

Comment: @Mico, see my response for a version that will update the list if that's what you want

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of generator expressions.

```
inner_lists = (inner_dict['b'] for inner_dict in myDict.values())
# if 'b' is not guaranteed to exist,
# replace inner_dict['b'] with inner_dict.get('b', [])
items = (item for ls in inner_lists for item in ls)
```

Now you can either use a `foo` loop

```
for item in items:
    # apply function
```

or `map`

```
transformed_items = map(func, items)
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple fixes could be made.

1. Don't use `is` when comparing two strings (`if key is "b":`)
2. Simply say `print(item)` instead of using `.format()`, since you only have one variable that you're printing, with no additional string formatting

Revised code:

```
for id, obj in myDict.items():
    for key, val in obj.items():
        if key == "b":
            for item in val:
                print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you will have a `b` key in every case, you can simply do:

```
for id, obj in myDict.items():
    for item in obj["b"]:
        print item
```