# How is python storing strings so that the 'is' operator works on literals?

Tags: python, string

In python

```
>>> a = 5
>>> a is 5
True
```

but

```
>>> a = 500
>>> a is 500
False
```

This is because it stores low integers as a single address. But once the numbers begin to be complex, each int gets its own unique address space. This makes sense to me.

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object.

So now, why does this not apply to strings? Are not strings just as complex as large integers (if not moreso)?

```
>>> a = '1234567'
>>> a is '1234567'
True
```

How does python use the same address for all string literals efficiently? It cant keep an array of every possible string like it does for numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't store an array of all possible strings, instead it has a hash table which point to memory addresses of all currently declared strings, indexed by the hash of the string.

For example

when you say `a = 'foo'`, it first hashes the string `foo` and checks if an entry already exists in the hash table. If yes, then variable `a` now references that address.

If no entry is found in the table, python allocates memory to store the string, hashes `foo` and adds an entry in the table with the address of the allocated memory.

See:

1. [How is the 'is' keyword implemented in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987958/how-is-the-is-keyword-implemented-in-python)
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning

Comment: `is` compares object `id`s

Comment: It compares memory addresses as well. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987958/how-is-the-is-keyword-implemented-in-python

Comment: id == memory address in CPython IIRC

Answer (score 3):

It's an optimisation technique called interning. CPython recognises the [equal values of **string constants**](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c21f17c6e9d3218812b593f6ec5647e91c16896b/Objects/codeobject.c#L59) and doesn't allocate extra memory for new instances but simply points to the same one (interns it), giving both the same `id()`.

One can play around to confirm that only constants are treated this way (simple operations like `b` are recognised):

```
# Two string constants
a = "aaaa"
b = "aa" + "aa"

# Prevent interpreter from figuring out string constant
c = "aaa"
c += "a"

print id(a)         # 4509752320
print id(b)         # 4509752320
print id(c)         # 4509752176 !!
```

However you can manually force a string to be mapped to an already existing one using [`intern()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#intern):

```
c = intern(c)

print id(a)         # 4509752320
print id(b)         # 4509752320
print id(c)         # 4509752320 !!
```

Other interpreters may do it differently. Since strings are immutable, changing one of the two will not change the other.

Comment: It looks like the range of predefined integers is -5 to +256.  All others seem to get created on the fly from literals, so "is" returns False.

Comment: Didnt mark as answer because you say "its optimization" but dont explain how its being stored, which is the question. Or in otherwords HOW are they doing the optimization.