# What is the Python class magic method for using is keyword?

Tags: python

I know that in python we can use `__eq__` method to check equality and `__iter__` when using in keyword. Is there any method for is keyword?

Comment: why are you wanting to override the "is" keyword? Checking if two memory addresses are the same leaves little room for addition.

Comment: [You cannot change the implementation of the `is` keyword.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2987999/10269808)

Comment: `is` is the identity operator, IOW it checks if two variables point to the same object. I fail to see how this could be overridden ;-)

Comment: I am not asking to override it. as @GranolaGuy guy pointed out. I want to know if there is any magic method for is. like if I say. if a is b: in this code. lets assume a and b are instances of some class. now for similar scenarios python has magic functions. but I couldnt find anything for is, Wondering if there is any.

Comment: `is` does not check if two things are an instance of the same class. `isinstance()` can do that. `is` checks if two things are the _same_ thing. There is not a magic method for `is` like .__is__()

Comment: That was just an example, Anyway isinstance can only say if something is an instance of a class. not their ids are the same. This can be a very lame question as i can just do id(a) == id(b). but Just wondering if there is any magic method for it.