# Why does comparing a variable to 0.0 return false?

Tags: python

I'm curious about the behavior of the following code:

```py
0.0 is 0.0 # True

a = 0.0
a is 0.0 # False
```

It seems to me that `a is 0.0` should evaluate to True. In my particular case I need to distinguish when a variable is 0.0 specifically, so `a == 0` will not work because it will fail when `a` is equal to False. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the 'is' keyword implemented in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987958/how-is-the-is-keyword-implemented-in-python)

Comment: I think I understand `is` (checks identity rather than equality), but this doesn't explain how to check for that `a` is specifically 0.0 and not False.

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator is used when the values of two operands are equal, then the condition becomes true.

The `is` operator evaluates to true if the variables on either side of the operator point to the same object and false otherwise.