# In Python, does "if" evaluates the conditional statements in boolean context?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.7

I am new to programming so apologies for not being able to frame the question properly but here's a more detailed version of the problem. If I run the following code:

```
age=2
if age:
   print("hello")
else:
   print("bye")
```

Output is "hello" which I read was due to age being evaluated to True.

But when I modify it to:

```
age=2
if age is True:
   print("hello")
else:
   print("bye")
```

The Output is "bye"

I was expecting the Output here to be True. Where is the gap in my understanding? I Would also be grateful if you could direct me to a link to study the topic. Thanks

Comment: Use `==` to compare integers by value, or `bool` to evaluate them as either true or false. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987958/how-is-the-is-keyword-implemented-in-python for details on how `is` works.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: In the first code you simply check if 'age' exists. In the second code you check if age is True however age is equal to the integer 2 (so not a bool). If you check age == 2 then this is True and "hello" is printed.

Comment: @JohnMommers not if it _exists_, if it's _truthy_.

Comment: @JohnMommers No, the first one does not check if `age` exists. If it doesn't exist, you'll get a `NameError`. It checks if `age` has a truthy value (which for `int` values means it is non-zero).

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand it now. The question has been marked duplicate and so following the original question also helped me in understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the title, yes, python evaluates objects in a boolean context when in an `if`.

The `is` keyword refers to identity, meaning that two values compared represent the same object.

[Here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/)'s an article that describes it.